# how to create a drop down menu for the answers of a survey app in php

Tags: php, web-applications, database-design, drop-down-menu, survey

I just started to build a survey application which contains different types of answers (e.g. checkboxes, radio buttons, yes/no, etc..

My problem is that I don't know how to show the answer for some questions such as "who are your favourite actors?". I thought about auto-completion or a drop-down box (e.g. in alphabetical order) from which users can select their favourite actors but I don't know how to do it.

I searched for similar questions like [How to create drop down menu [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929977/how-to-create-drop-down-menu), [Creating A Drop-down Menu,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744515/creating-a-drop-down-menu), [PHP Dynamic Drop Down Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496603/php-dynamic-drop-down-menu), and I read [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php15p2.html) however still I am confused how to make this type of answer (also because I don't know how could I design them in my database).

For designing my database, I thought of creating 4 tables:

**Questions (questionId, questionText, questionType)**

**Answers (answerId, questionId, answer)**

**UsersAnswer (userAnswerId, AnswerId, UserId, userAnswer)**

**Users (userId, userName, .. )**

I'd appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need jquery and it's dimensions:

Put at top of page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dimensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Now you need function to call...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){      setAutoComplete("searchField", "results", "autocomplete.php?part=");  });
</script>
```

Now for input (Client side):

```
<label>Actors: </label><input type="text" id="searchField" name="searchField">
```

PHP (Server-side):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbUsername', 'dbPassword');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db("database")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM  sks_color");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$colors[]=$row['name'];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);        // check the parameter
if(isset($_GET['part']) and $_GET['part'] != '')
{
// initialize the results array
$results = array();        // search colors
foreach($colors as $color)
{
// if it starts with 'part' add to results
if( strpos($color, $_GET['part']) === 0 ){
$results[] = $color;
}
}         // return the array as json with PHP 5.2
echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Keep in mind that this is returning a JSON object...

Links:

- [AJAX auto-complete PHP](http://www.sks.com.np/article/9/ajax-autocomplete-using-php-mysql.html)
- [Tutorial](http://www.script-tutorials.com/autocomplete-with-php-jquery-mysql-and-xml/)

Comment: Actually, at the beginning I wanted to do the same (let users fill in textbox), but my professor was not agree and asked me to make alphabetical choice or auto-completion.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does IMDB have a plugin that allows you to reference their database of actors? Because they literally have every actor/actress on their site. That might allow you to do an auto-complete if IMDB has one.

Comment: I have a complete list of Imdb actors/actresse in my database :) I just donno how to use them for autocomplete or drop down..

Comment: Editted, hope that helps.